Cannot compile PJSIP with TLS/OpenSSL support
I'm trying to develop an iOS swift voip application and I chose PJSIP to work with. I have it working but I need to compile the library with TLS/OpenSSL support because I cannot register an account in my SIP server and I'm suspecting this could be the problem.
The steps I followed are:

I clone the pjsip project and I configure the config_site.h with this values:

    #define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1 
    #include <pj/config_site_sample.h>


I download the openssl library and I compile it with these commands:
export CROSS_TOP=/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
export CROSS_SDK=iPhoneOS17.5.sdk
export CC="/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64"
./Configure iphoneos-cross --prefix=/Users/bantona/openssl/
make
make install


I prepare the PJSIP compilation running these commands:


    export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
    # arm64 simulator
    ARCH="-arch arm64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m64" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m64" MIN_IOS="-mios-simulator-version-min=13.0" ./configure-iphone --with-ssl=/Users/bantona/openssl

The expected outcome of this command (according to the PJSIP lib installation guide) is something like:
    ...
    checking for OpenSSL installations..
    checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
    checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
    aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
    aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
    checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
    checking for ERR_load_BIO_strings in -lcrypto... yes
    checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... yes
    OpenSSL library found, SSL support enabled
    ...

but I'm getting:
    ...
    Using SSL prefix... /Users/bantona/openssl
    checking for OpenSSL installations..
    checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
    checking for ERR_load_BIO_strings in -lcrypto... no
    checking for ERR_get_error in -lcrypto... no
    checking for SSL_CTX_new in -lssl... no
    ** OpenSSL libraries not found **
    ...

I'm working with a M2 Macbook Pro.
I've been trying more approaches (brew installation, config_site.h with #define PJ_HAS_SSL_SOCK 1 and many more) but nothing ends up working.
Any help would be appreciated and let me know if any of you need more specific information.
Cheers,
Borja.
